# Getting the age in months using Java Time API

Tags: java, java-time, period

I wrote what I thought would be simple time API call to get the amount of months and years between two `LocalDate`s.  However, when I am doing my tests the numbers do not seem to be computing correctly.

https://repl.it/@trajano/LocalDate-Period-Ages?language=java

```java
import java.time.*;
import java.time.temporal.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    {
        User user = new User();
        user.setDateOfBirth(LocalDate.of(2014, 11, 11));
        assertEquals(0, user.getAgeInMonths(LocalDate.of(2014, 11, 11)));
        assertEquals(0, user.getAgeInMonths(LocalDate.of(2014, 11, 12)));
        assertEquals(0, user.getAgeInMonths(LocalDate.of(2014, 12, 10)));
        assertEquals(1, user.getAgeInMonths(LocalDate.of(2014, 12, 11)));
        assertEquals(1, user.getAgeInMonths(LocalDate.of(2014, 12, 25)));
        assertEquals(1, user.getAgeInMonths(LocalDate.of(2015, 1, 6)));
        assertEquals(1 + 12, user.getAgeInMonths(LocalDate.of(2016, 1, 6)));
        assertEquals(1 + 12 * 2, user.getAgeInMonths(LocalDate.of(2017, 1, 6)));
        assertEquals(1 + 12 * 3, user.getAgeInMonths(LocalDate.of(2018, 1, 6)));    }
  }
}

class User {
  LocalDate dateOfBirth;

  public void setDateOfBirth(LocalDate dateOfBirth) {
    this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
  }

  public int getAge(final LocalDate processingDate) {

    return (int) Period.between(dateOfBirth, processingDate.plusDays(1)).get(ChronoUnit.YEARS);
  }

  public int getAgeInMonths(final LocalDate processingDate) {
    return (int) Period.between(dateOfBirth, processingDate.plusDays(1)).get(ChronoUnit.MONTHS);
  }

  public int getAge() {
    return getAge(LocalDate.now());
  }

  public int getAgeInMonths() {
    return getAgeInMonths(LocalDate.now());
  }
}
```

I tried both `Period.` and `ChronoUnit.MONTHS` but the assertions fail. Using the code from 
[Java Time period in decimal number of years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46533468/java-time-period-in-decimal-number-of-years)
[Java 8 Date time for calculating age in decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46985522/java-8-date-time-for-calculating-age-in-decimals)

```
return (int) Period.between(dateOfBirth, processingDate.plusDays(1)).get(ChronoUnit.MONTHS);
```

and

```
return (int) ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(dateOfBirth, processingDate.plusDays(1));
```

UPDATE: I made a mistake on the assertions.  So I fixed them.

Comment: Is it just the last four assertions that fail?  If I was born on 11 November, I'd still be one month old, not two, by 6 January.

Comment: it starts failing in 
`assertEquals(0, user.getAgeInMonths(LocalDate.of(2014, 12, 10)));`

Comment: That could be because of the `plusDays(1)` - you're figuring out the age on 11 December, not 10 December.

Comment: That's because you add one day inside `getAgeInMonths` : `processingDate.plusDays(1)`. Why are you doing that?

Comment: The API says its "exclusive" for the second field.

Comment: But if I take that out it still fails in `assertEquals(2, user.getAgeInMonths(LocalDate.of(2015, 1, 6)));`

Comment: Yes, and I have already explained why.

Comment: Only full periods (in your case, months) are taken into account when using the Java Time API.

Answer (score 2):

My version would probably be:

```
public int getAgeInMonths(LocalDate processingDate) {
    return Math.toIntExact(ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(dateOfBirth, processingDate));
}
```

As a matter of taste I find it completely superfluous to declare the parameter `final`. Whether the method modifies the parameter or not is an implementation detail not relevant in the method signature.

I prefer `Math.toIntExact` as a safer way of converting from `long` to `int`. It will throw an exception in case of int overflow.

Also as a matter of taste, when all we are interested in is months, we don’t need to go through the `Period` class.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what finally worked

```
public int getAge(final LocalDate processingDate) {

    return Period.between(dateOfBirth, processingDate).getYears();
}

public int getAgeInMonths(final LocalDate processingDate) {

    return (int) Period.between(dateOfBirth, processingDate).toTotalMonths();

}
```

Comment: Now I do.  I was looking for `getTotalMonths`